# How to handle multiple dispatches from UI (slider, input, ...) in ngrx store

Tags: angular, performance, ngrx

I have an UI with a lot of properties like width, height, x, y, opactity, etc.. You can imagine **Figma** or another visual editor. The changes should be immediately visible and not after click.

The app holds a global state with all elements (each element has these properties). After selecting an element, the properties can be edited. Every edit will cause a dispatch to the store which causes the UI freezing or lagging.

Is there a better way to update these values? I could create an own state for the selected element and update the values there, but I don't think this will help a lot. Of course I already tried with debounceTime but this is not possible because the this causes a delay in the UI. Or keep the data local in the component and update them directly, afterwards update the global store with debounce?

Any suggestion on how this could be done by architecure? I'm not even sure if a store makes sense or it will be better to have direct references from the UI to the object.

Comment: so the user can change HTML element properties such as width, height, etc.. currently shown in the component? I wonder how are these HTML/custom components rendered in the DOM, are you using `ngFor` in some cases? Additionally, what is the reason behind using `ngrx`? Are these changes in the UI need to be reminded? like preferences? so the next time the user logs in, those changes will be there?

Comment: Have you tried changing the detection strategy of your components from `Default` to `onPush`? or maybe, if you are using the latest version of Angular, have you tried using `signals` for handling the changes in the template?

Comment: @Andres2142 the data is persisted in a DB after saving manually. I'm using `ngFor` with trackBy. Aswell onPush and signals but I saw that I do some things in the effect() of signals, which sould not trigger everytime the signals changed. Sadly it does, on every change and I dont know how to execute the signal one time initially. This could cause the lag in the UI. But I'm still not sure if ngrx is made for multiple dispatches at once (caused e.g by a UI slider).

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how your project is, how the code is, how is the architecture of it, etc... I can suggest using `AngularDevTools` and detect where you have these high change detection spikes, maybe some logic of some components doesn't require to detect changes and it could run out of the ngZone maybe?

Comment: Also, maybe when changes happen by the user, you could make use of `defer blocks` for lazy loading components in your template if you are using Angular v17, when something changed, switch back to a `loading...` or something

Comment: Hard to say what's the root of your problem because we don't have the code and the requirements. You say "Every edit will cause a dispatch to the store which causes the UI freezing or lagging" but don't provide any info about what is the reason for those lags. Also it is not clear if you need NGRX at all and how it is currently used. As for the NGRX related issues it can be that your selectors are not implemented correctly, so every change of the state triggers all possible subscriptions instead of triggering just one, which then causes the whole UI to be redrawn. Or reducers take to much time